# Send data to webService in react-native

Tags: react-native

Hi I'm working on a app in react-native which is using the latitude and longitude of the user phone position. I'm also using a webService that let me retrieve some data about the user. I want now to send the latitude and longitude to the webservice how can I do that ?

```
getData(){
    const url = "https://somewebsite.com/webservice/app/ws.php"
    fetch(url) 
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: res
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("get data error:" + error);
    });
  }
```

```
displayPosition = () => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude),
          longitude: JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude),
          error: null,
        });
        console.log(this.state.latitude)

      }, 
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
  }
```

Will it work if I do : `` `https://somewebsite.com/webservice/app/ws.php?lo=${this.state.longitude}&la=${this.state.latitude} `` `

Answer (score 1):

You need to use POST method to send data to your backend. You can use `axios`. Here is a very basic example:

```
axios.post('https://somewebsite.com/webservice/app/ws.php', {
    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
    longitude: position.coords.longitude
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: So with that I will only be able to send the two parameters, but I won't be able to retrieve the data ? Is that correct ?

Comment: No no, you can send whatever you want. This is just an example. It receives Object, Array and others. 

I do not completely understand the second part. You won't be able to retrieve data? It depends on your backend code.

Comment: I mean that I need to get the data and show It in my component. But I also need to send the two parameters, latitude and longitude to the webservice in order to achieve some filter. So can I get the data and send the two parameters with ur code ? I do not know if I'm clear

Comment: It all depends on your backend part. If you have a POST method to save and handle it, then the answer is YES.